# Iterate through a list of methods?

Tags: python, loops, methods, iteration

I have a dataframe and I want to create a list of dataframes produced by the methods .mean(), and .median().

Is there any way to do that like this?:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(md)
my_list = [grouped_df.i for i in [mean(), median()]
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward and no-nonsense way would be:

```
[grouped_df.mean(), grouped_df.median()]
```

Any alternative is really unnecessarily more complex:

```
[i() for i in (grouped_df.mean, grouped_df.median)]
```

```
[getattr(grouped_df, i)() for i in ('mean', 'median')]
```

I'm not sure about the class structure here, but maybe something like this works too:

```
[i(grouped_df) for i in (df.mean, df.median)]
```

You'd need to get to a somewhat substantially long list of methods, or a much more dynamic/functional code, to make any of these approaches worth it.

Comment: Wow, the getattr approach really worked and allowed me to add more statistics and to apply common methods like .round(3).astype(str). Thank you very much!